# not getting desired Json response

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I have written php file which takes an array,explodes it and perform query.

PROBLEM:

array i pass is:`127 129 121`

On android side in the logcat JSON response only contains query result for first item of array.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "lat": "0",
            "lng": "0",
            "uid": "127"
        },
        {
            "lat": "-33.866",
            "lng": "151.195",
            "uid": "127"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1,
    "message": "lat lng"
}
```

but i pass the same array and test the file in browser(using postman) i get the following json response:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "lat": "0",
            "lng": "0",
            "uid": "127"
        },
        {
            "lat": "-33.866",
            "lng": "151.195",
            "uid": "127"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1,
    "message": "lat lng"
}

{
    "users": [
        {
            "lat": "-18.142",
            "lng": "178.431",
            "uid": "129"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1,
    "message": "lat lng"
}

{
    "users": [
        {
            "lat": "37.423",
            "lng": "-122.091",
            "uid": "121"
        },
        {
            "lat": "-31.9906066",
            "lng": "148.8977051",
            "uid": "121"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1,
    "message": "lat lng"
}
```

I want the records of all users as this json response. why am i getting different response on php and android side??  i want records of all the users i have passed in array. HELP!!
PHP CODE:

```
 <?php
 // array for JSON response
$response = array();
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["uid"])  ) {

    $uid= explode(' ', $_GET['uid']);

foreach ($uid as $value) {

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT lat,lng,uid FROM location1 WHERE uid='$value' AND date='27-11-2014' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $response["users"] = array();
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
                $users = array();

                 $users["lat"] = $row["lat"];
                $users["lng"] = $row["lng"];
                $users["uid"] = $row["uid"];
                // user node
                array_push($response["users"], $users);

             }
        $response["success"] = 1;
     $response["message"] = "lat lng";
    // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response)."<br>";
    }
    else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response)."<br>";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

HERE is the android code:

```
   package com.example.newtabs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.utils.Constants;
import com.example.utils.Utils;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class Circle_SubTabFriends_Map extends Activity {
    String user_email,user_id;
    Button add;
    String end_lat;
    String end_lng;
    String[] lv_items;
    int len;
    String s;
    String detail;
    StringBuilder sb;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    static String url_circle_friends = Constants.url_circle_friends;
    static String url_location_friend_circle = Constants.url_location_friend_circle;
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_USERS = "users";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";
    private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    // users JSONArray
    JSONArray users = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // new GetCurrentLocation().execute();
        new LoadAllUsers().execute();
        new GetCurrentLocation().execute();
      //function for maintaining session
            user_id=Utils.GetPreferences("user_id",this);
            user_email=Utils.GetPreferences("user",this);
            if(user_email.length() <0)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Locator_Registration.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        setContentView(R.layout.locator_map);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Circle_SubTabFriends_AddCircle.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all users by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
}

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user_email));
            // getting JSON string from URL

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_circle_friends, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("circle_subtabfrinds ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // users found
                    // Getting Array of users
                    users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);
                    lv_items = new String[users.length()];
                    len = lv_items.length;
                    // looping through All Users
                    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        lv_items[i] = id+","+name;
                        Log.d("CHECKING! ", id+name);

                    }

                } else {
                    // no products found

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all users
            //pDialog.dismiss();    
        }

    }
    /**       
     * Background Async Task to Get History
     * */
    class GetCurrentLocation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        /**
         * Getting user's history in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success; 
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String[] outputStrArr = new String[len];

                        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            outputStrArr[i] = lv_items[i];

                            String[] separated = outputStrArr[i].split(",");
                            s = "";
                            String idpart = separated[0];
                            String namepart = separated[1];

                            detail = idpart + " " ;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), detail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            sb.append(detail);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), /*selectedItems[i]*/ sb,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String a=sb.toString();
                        a=a.trim();

                        Log.d("A!", a);

                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", a));
                        // getting history by making HTTP request
                        // Note that user history url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_location_friend_circle, "GET", params);
                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("circle location", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            Log.d("RUNNN", "SUCCESS");
                            // successfully received history
                            users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS); // JSON Array
                            Log.d("array users", users.toString());

                            lv_items = new String[users.length()];
                            len = lv_items.length;

                            // get first object from JSON Array
                            for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                                String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                                String lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);
                                lv_items[i] = lat + ',' + lng;
                                Log.d("FOOL!", lv_items[i].toString());

                            }
                        } else {
                            // history not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    -18.142, 178.431), 2));
            sb = new StringBuilder();

            String[] outputStrArr = new String[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                outputStrArr[i] = lv_items[i];
                String[] separated = outputStrArr[i].split(",");
                s = "";

                    //end_lat = separated[0];
                    //end_lng = separated[1];
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "end"+end_lat+"-"+end_lng,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String latpart = separated[0];
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latpart,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String lngpart = separated[1];
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double
                        .valueOf( latpart).doubleValue(), Double
                        .valueOf(lngpart).doubleValue())));

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `array i pass is:127 129 121`. Please show the code where you are doing that.

Comment: i have added the android code in my post. have a look

Comment: But you did not post the code i asked for. And i cannot see the value of a in `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", a));`. And then i specifically asked to show how you sent the three values in a GET request. Which you didn't. Please do.

Comment: i have pasted the code. lv_items[i] is my array [127,129,121] I use d string builder and then my array became 127 129 121 . sb.append(detail); is having this value and then i saved it to string variable 'a'

Comment: then i send 'a' to database. i have also commented the code a bit. have a look

Comment: Send a to database? Why? What do you mean? But i asked you to show how you would use that in a GET request. You still did not show that. Commented a bit? You did not add any comment. Instead you made your code unreadable with all these ** **.

Comment: i send 'a' to database which is an array then explode it and apply query on it to get records of all items present in the array. apologies for that, let me undo the changes

Comment: No. a is not an array as far as i can see but a String. The value of a is "127 129 121". And you are not sending a to a database but to a php script. I asked you already two times to show how you send a to that script. You still did not provide that info.

Comment: sir! from what i know params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", a)); in doInBackground of async task sends the value of 'a' to php script. there is nothing else i did.

Comment: Indeed very plausible that that is done in doInBackground. But you were already three times asked to show how you do that. That means that you should show the used code. Ant why are you not commenting on the array versus string issue?

Comment: sir kindly check my json response i think there is some problem with it that is why only one user's data is returned in json response. it would be king of u to review my php file. i am providing my android code too now. and yes 'a' is a string variable in which i have saved the contents of array.

Comment: You posted far too much irrelevant code. `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_location_friend_circle, "GET", params);`Thats the line where params (which contains the string a with the three ids) get send by the parser as GET request. So now dig into your parser class to see and tell us what it does with params exactly.